# Which way is easiest to handle Facebook Authentication to your own site?

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, resolve

I'm creating a project where I want a user to authenticate with Facebook.
I've been trying with `OauthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient` but I can't resolve this.. I can't find the right DLL for this..

Does anyone know what to use for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can pick Facebook API for this.Which is available for JS too.

The basic idea is:

1. You register on Facebook like a developer
2. Create an APP on Facebook
3. Obtain security (unique to your app) key
4. Use that key in API to guide your user in authentication process.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Tho there is other methods for you to authenticate with Facebook.
follow this video on youtube and you 1 step closer :)
But I don't know why you can't resolve as I have the same problem.. I will tell you if I find out how!

[http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsO0G-8idyo][]